# How to prevent Origin:null in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to do `webview.postUrl` in android code

it automatically adds `Origin:null` in the headers

How to prevent this?

My Code below

```
import butterknife.Bind;
.....
@Bind(R.id.webview)
WebView webview;
....
....
protected final void loadUrl(String url) {
    webview.postUrl("http://localhost:8080/myapp/login", mypostdata);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your webview code block ?

Comment: WebView is not my code, it is coming from android sdk

Answer (score 0):

The **Origin** is set to **null** probably because of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) that is enabled on the API you're requesting.

[Check this page for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)

AFAIK, the [postUrl](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#postUrl(java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D)) method does not allow updating Origin.

I managed to send a custom Origin URL using the following **workaround** :

```
val originURL = "https://www.origin.url/"
val htmlContent = """
    <html>
        <body onload='form1.submit()'>
            <form id='form1' action='http://localhost:8080/myapp/login' method='POST'>
                <input name='POST_PARAM_1' type='hidden' value='VALUE_OF_PARAM1' />
                <input name='POST_PARAM_2' type='hidden' value='VALUE_OF_PARAM2' />
                <input name='POST_PARAM_3' type='hidden' value='VALUE_OF_PARAM3' />
                <input name='POST_PARAM_4' type='hidden' value='VALUE_OF_PARAM4' />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
""".trimIndent()

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(originURL , htmlContent ,  "text/html" , "UTF-8" , null)
```

Instead of using **postUrl** which doesn't support sending custom headers, I called [loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), this method expects a baseURL (which is the Origin URL).

Based on the documentation:

> Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL
> for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs
> and when applying JavaScript's **same-origin policy**. The historyUrl is
> used for the history entry.

The WebView will load an HTML page that automatically POSTs parameters to your URL.